# unexpected identifier for input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I am trying to display edit and delete buttons dynamically.
- can you tell me how to fix the error unexpected identifier.
- and how to achieve edit and delete functionalities
- providing code in codepen below
  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZRMPW?editors=1011

  ```
  $('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var div = "<div><span>"+$('#name').val()+"</span><span>"+$('#email').val()+"</span><input data-name="edit" type="button" value="Edit" name="editHistory"></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input..
      alert(div);

      $('.gettingValues').html(div); //apendd the div
      $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form
      localStorage.clear();
  });
  ```

Comment: You are enclosing double quotes in double quotes,cancelling each other. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: @RubyRacer can you update in codepen...consfusing not sure which quotes :(

Comment: Example, data-name="edit" has double quotes`"edit"`. And it is enclosed in double quotes. Either change all the inner double quotes to single (`'edit'`)or the outter ones. Not only in this example, be more careful in your syntax.

Comment: I'm posting as answer, it will be clearer once you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code-

1. You are using double quotes inside double quotes, and they cancel out each other. So, change the following code -

   ```
   var div = "<div><span>"+$('#name').val()+"</span><span>"+$('#email').val()+"</span><input data-name="edit" type="button" value="Edit" name="editHistory"></div>";
   ```

   to this -

   ```
   var div = "<div><span>"+$('#name').val()+"</span><span>"+$('#email').val()
           + "</span><input data-name='edit' type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'></div>";
   ```

   Notice that I have enclosed the `data-name` and `type` in single quotes.
2. When you are dynamically creating the elements, the events cannot be bound to them directly, so your `click()` function will never be triggered. You should convert it to-

   ```
   $('.gettingValues').on('click', "input[name='editHistory']", function(){
      data = $(this).data('name');
      console.log(data);
      editHistoryAPI(data);
   });
   ```

   The reason behind doing the above is that when you have to bind an event to a dynamically created element, you should use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and delegate the event to the nearest static element which wraps the dynamic element. This static element in your case is the `div` with class `gettingValues`.

Updated pen- http://codepen.io/schikara/pen/zqzjGW?editors=1011

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you...how to edit my values or delete it...any idea

Comment: What are you trying to edit and delete? Is it the values entered by the user in the `name`, `email` and `message` fields?

Comment: Yes...the values submitted from form fields

Comment: You can store the values in the data attributes of your wrapper `span` elements and then fetch them inside the `click` function. Then, simply display them using `.val()` function in your `input` elements.

Comment: can you update the edit and delete functionality in codepen...not sure how to achieve it :(

Comment: but when I give second value the first value is disappearing do you know the reason...I wanted to display all the values in a list

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as an answer (after the comment). Change all double quotes `"` to single quotes `'` within blocks of string:

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = "<div><span>"+$('#name').val()+"</span><span>"+$('#email').val()+"</span><input data-name='edit' type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input..
    alert(div);

    $('.gettingValues').html(div); //apendd the div
    $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

Comment: Thank you...how to edit my values or delete it...any idea

Comment: Check @shekhar's answer, I think it covers most of your problems.